# OpenVPN user certificates

Tags: openvpn

I have problem with understanding of combination of `OpenVPN` with `EasyRsa`.
I have read [this instructions](https://community.openvpn.net/openvpn/wiki/EasyRSA3-OpenVPN-Howto)
I am not understanding how client keys signing and revoking.
When I sign on `CA` server for user certificate and keys, `openVPN` server determines that user had signed his certificates and keys by same `CA` server and allows user to connect?
Similar to `https` with trusted certification server(example LetsEncrypt)
Right?

If i want to block user from access to `openVPN`, i need to revoke certificate on `CA` server.
But how `openVPN` server will understand that this user has no more rights to access `openVPN`?
Only with help of extra certificate revoke list?
That is generated with `easyrsa gen-crl` and synced/copied from `CA` server to `openVPN` server?
However if user certificate is expired, so `openVPN` server will simply not accept connection?
Am i right?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To revoke certificates, you create a list of them and tell your OpenVPN server that when clients enter, they need to be verified using this list.

Using the "./revoke-full client_name" command, you add forbidden clients to the crl.pem file. Then, copy this file to the server configuration directory.
In order for the server to check this file when clients enter, it needs to enter the line "crl-verify crl.pem" in the configuration file.
Attention! If this string appears in the configuration file, but this file does not exist, the server will stop letting all clients!

Comment: Thanks. Especially for part were server locks out all users.